# How to assign multiple values to multiple variables in python (when looping occurs)

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4

When using the following loop, how can I create a separate variable for each value generated (while looping occurs)?

Eg: with n = 1, m1 = 1; n = 2, m2 = 2; n = 3, m3 = 3; etc.

How can I print each variable generated (m1, m2, etc.) with it's assigned value as separate items?

```
for n in range(11):
    print(n)
```

Comment: You need to learn about lists.

Comment: You are asking how to create the variables `ni` with i from 1 to 3? Have you tried using lists

Answer (score 1):

The following code demonstrates one approach that you could try taking:

```
>>> variables = {}
>>> for n in range(11):
    variables[f'm{n}'] = n


>>> for key, value in variables.items():
    print(f'{key} = {value}')


m0 = 0
m1 = 1
m2 = 2
m3 = 3
m4 = 4
m5 = 5
m6 = 6
m7 = 7
m8 = 8
m9 = 9
m10 = 10
>>>
```